# Set pictureBox's image property created on Run-time CF C#

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, windows-ce, picturebox

I create a pictureBox on Run-time and then to access to it I use this code:

```
foreach(Control mycontrol in panel.Controls){
  if(control.Name == "picBox1"){
    //here I can work with my pictureBox
  }
}
```

But once I am inside the if sentence I can't put `control.Image`. Is there any property of Control which I could use to manage the picBox1's Image property?

**SOLUTION** As Rajesh suggested, casting the control solves the problem. I was trying to cast it by using `(PictureBox)control.Image` and it was **wrong**.

The **right way** of doing it is writting Rajesh's code: `((PictureBox)control).Image`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the following code

```
((PictureBox)Control).Image = /*image */
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! that solve my problem. I tried writing `(PictureBox)control.Image` and it was wrong. With the double parenthesis the problem is solved